instagram like bottom screen navigation
Here is Video of instagram bottom behaviour
Hello i am trying to achieve bottom screen navigation as like Instagram in flutter.
i have tried tab bar,bottom bar but i am not able to achieve it.
i have also search on GitHub and google but not get any solution.
can any help me which Widget is used? how can i achieve same UI .
Here is my code.
class AddStorySwipeRoute extends GetView<HomeController> {
  const AddStorySwipeRoute({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppTheme.primary,
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
        height: kToolbarHeight,
        child: TabBar(
          tabs: const [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Post',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  'Story',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  'Clips',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
          labelStyle: AppUtils.textBlueSFMedium14,
          unselectedLabelStyle: AppUtils.textGreylblSFMedium14,
          unselectedLabelColor: AppTheme.greylblColor,
          indicator: const BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
              bottom: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                width: 2.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          indicatorWeight: 3.0,
          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
          isScrollable: true,
          controller: controller.tabController,
          // tabAlignment: TabAlignment.center,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
          controller: controller.tabController,
          // physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            CameraRoute(1),
            AddFeedPostRoute(),
            CameraRoute(1),
          ]),
    );
  }
}


One way to achieve this would be through the following Widget hierarchy:
Scaffold 
  > Stack
    > Your main page content
    > Positioned // make this positioned `bottom`/`left`/`right`: `0`
      > Container // Here you add the shape (Stadium border), and other styling
        > Row // main axis alignment: `.end`
          > [Text, Text, Text]

This would help you create a "floating" bottom navigation bar that is positioned and styled the way they do it on Instagram.

Hello @Keiwan Thanks for your reply i am able to getting this. but there also menu is scrollable with center text highlight as like instagram  that i am not acheiving

Thank you for your reply. I'm sadly not that familiar with Instagram's bottom nav bar. If you can explain the behavior you want in as much detail as you possibly can I might be able to help!

Hi @Keiwan i have uploaded video link of it please check it.

Thanks! I have watched the video and if I understand your correctly you want to recreate the effect of having the selected item in the center?
If so, there is a package called smooth_page_indicator (link here) that can easily achieve that effect (see section #scrolling-dots-effect fixedCenter: true.
I would use it as a piece of my bottom nav bar component.

Hi @Keiwan Thanks for you reply. sure i will try it and test it.
